# очередь загрузки js фалов yii2 фреймворке

Tags: php, javascript, yii2

я использую сборшики для js файлов своем проекте 
и отключил собственные  jquery yii в конфиге

вот в чем проблема при валидации формы yii.js скрипты не работаю так как
они подключаются первыми 
выглядит так

```html
<script src="/assets/a20e19d8/yii.validation.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/a20e19d8/yii.activeForm.js"></script>

<script src="/dist/assets/js/vendor.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="/dist/assets/js/app.bundle.js"></script>
```

а нужно так

```html
<script src="/dist/assets/js/vendor.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="/dist/assets/js/app.bundle.js"></script>

<script src="/assets/a20e19d8/yii.validation.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/a20e19d8/yii.activeForm.js"></script>
```

ошибка в том что jquery не определена
нашел решение в том что бы подключать его в на чале body

public $jsOptions = ['position' => \yii\web\View::POS_HEAD];

но хотелось бы что бы страница грузилась быстрее и не подключать огромный файл в начал
и еще вопрос можно ли изменить имена этих файлов yii.js на my-yii.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы можете создать новый класс ассет

```
class BundleAsset extends AssetBundle
{
    public $basePath = '@webroot';
    public $baseUrl = '@web';
    public $js = [
         '/assets/js/vendor.bundle.js'
         '/assets/js/app.bundle.js'
    ];
}
```

А затем указать его в **AppAsset** (на чистом шаблоне Yii2 Advanced он регистрируется в layouts/main.php)

```
class AppAsset extends AssetBundle
{
    public $basePath = '@webroot';
    public $baseUrl = '@web';
    public $depends = [
        'frontend\assets\BundleAsset',
        'yii\web\YiiAsset',
        'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset',
    ];
}
```